# Find process with most child processes and the child process count

Tags: unix

What command should I use?

```
ps --no-headers  --ppid xxx | wc -l
```

I use this command to count the child processes, but I don't entirely know how to get the process with most children and if the code line is even correct

Comment: You will get better results if you move your question to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour). Stack Overflow is a forum about programming.

Comment: Not a big fan of parsing the output of `ps`, but perhaps you just want `ps -o ppid= -ax | awk '{count[$1]++} END {for( pid in count) print count[pid], pid}' | sort -nr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ ps -ax -o ppid= | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | sed 2q
 429     1
  58  1970
```

That show that there are 429 children of process 1, and 58 children of process 1970.  The options for `ps` will vary depending on the scope of the processes you want to consider.